# How can I bold a context menu item?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to make the first item in a tray icon's context menu bold. It should be easy but I don't find my answer anywhere. Can someone please point me in the right direction? This is the code that I'm using to render the items:

```
void MenuItemWin::CreateNative(
    LPMENUITEMINFO itemInfo, HMENU nativeParentMenu, bool registerNative)
{
    ZeroMemory(itemInfo, sizeof(MENUITEMINFO)); 
    itemInfo->cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    itemInfo->wID = ++UIWin::nextItemId;
    itemInfo->dwItemData = (ULONG_PTR) this;
    itemInfo->fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_DATA;

    HMENU nativeSubmenu = 0;
    if (this->IsSeparator())
    {
        itemInfo->fType = MFT_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        itemInfo->fMask = itemInfo->fMask | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_STATE;
        itemInfo->fType = MFT_STRING;
        itemInfo->fState = this->IsEnabled() ? MFS_ENABLED : MFS_DISABLED;
        itemInfo->dwTypeData = (LPWSTR) this->wideOldLabel.c_str();

        AutoPtr<MenuWin> wsubmenu = this->submenu.cast<MenuWin>();
        if (!wsubmenu.isNull())
            nativeSubmenu = wsubmenu->CreateNative(registerNative);

        itemInfo->hSubMenu = nativeSubmenu;

        if (this->IsCheck())
        {
            itemInfo->fState |= this->GetState() ? MFS_CHECKED : MFS_UNCHECKED;
        }
        else if (!this->iconPath.empty())
        {
            HBITMAP bitmap = UIWin::LoadImageAsBitmap(iconPath,
                GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON));
            if (bitmap)
            {
                itemInfo->fMask = itemInfo->fMask | MIIM_BITMAP;
                itemInfo->hbmpItem = bitmap;
            }
            else
            {
                std::string error = Win32Utils::QuickFormatMessage(GetLastError());
                Logger::Get("UI.MenuItem")->Error("Could not load icon (%s): %s",
                    iconPath.c_str(), error.c_str());
            }
        }
    }

    if (registerNative)
    {
        NativeItemBits* bits = new NativeItemBits;
        bits->id = itemInfo->wID;
        bits->parentMenu = nativeParentMenu;
        bits->submenu = nativeSubmenu;
        this->nativeItems.push_back(bits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647996(v=vs.85).aspx. I think it's the default item that is bolded.

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? This is *certainly* not C code, so I have no idea what that tag is doing there. It does look like C++, but it's not plain Win32 API, so you're missing at least one tag...

Comment: @CodyGray, it does have `CreateFile`, so my suggestion should still work if it's the right one.

Comment: @chris: Agreed, I upvoted your comment. I was aiming to post an answer of my own, with some sample code, I just couldn't figure out what dialect it should be in. Of course, it bears emphasizing that this feature should not be abused simply to make a menu item bold. The only item that should be bold is the *default* menu item, the one that can be invoked automatically by double-clicking on the icon.

Comment: Yes I think I posted the wrong code. I updated the question with the rendering function. This is from a framework called Titanium.

Comment: Question, should I blend in `MFS_DEFAULT` somewhere in there? I mean, I need to add another function to handle the "default" state on menu items, right?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items

Comment: Yes, you need to include the `MFS_DEFAULT` style.